Why we are establishing concepts in a way of collection?
I'm learning Topology and Measure Theory recently, and it is kind new to see their way to define the very important concepts.
For instance, the concept of topology, sigma-algebra, and semiring. Why they are so much similar when we are establishing these concepts and why we are using intersection or union or complement?

Mathematics fundamentally is an abstraction that models some reality. So your basically asking: why reality is as it is? Which is a rather philosophical question.
